# Degenerate perturbation theory for general operators

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Usually we are told about perturbation theory for either Hermitian or for Symmetric operators (real or complex ones). However, I have encountered a problem, where whatever kind of representation of the total operator (an effective Hamiltonian of the system) in an "unperturbed + perturbation" form I choose: $\hat H = \hat H_0 + \hat V$ , I could not force both $\hat H_0$, and $\hat V$ be either Hermitian or Symmetric. Usually, most interesting problems in QM are such.

So, I wonder, is there the most general perturbation theory for this case? And what about the case when $\hat H_0$ has degenerate eigenvalues?

My particular case is the following:
$\hat H_0$ is symmetric, and $\hat V$ can be made anti-symmetric. This is the best I can get.

An additional question: when $\hat V$, for instance, is not even a normal matrix, therefore, $\hat V^{\dagger} \hat V \ne \hat V \hat V^{\dagger}$) or even both $\hat H_0, \hat V$ are not diagonalizable (have Jordan blocks), is there a kind of perturbation theory for this case?

Comment: Have you seen Kato, [Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf) ?

Comment: Thank you @Keith McClary for your suggestion, I will have a closer look at this one

Comment: @Keith McClary I am not quite sure that pert. theory for eigenvectors of non-normal operators is covered here. At least can not see any mentions in the content, and subject index.
May be I am just too naive and there is not such thing as perturbation theory for a general linear operator on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Chapter two covers the general case.